# ApplicationXtender?

Tags: documentation, emc

Where can I find free technical documentation on EMC Application EXtender? This is a distributed system for "Storage, Organization, and Management of Business-Critical Information".

The IT team where I'm in has on his machines an installation of a server of this product, but I'm having troubles finding knowledge about it.

There are Microsoft Windows or Web-based clients. The administration is "easy", but i have no manual or documentation that can help me understand, monitor or fix...

Comment: I am systems engineer for a company that is an OEM for the AX product line. If you would like to contact me off list, I might be able to help you with your search.

Comment: Answers should be public so that other people can benefit from them in the future. Taking things "off list" doesn't help others who are looking to solve the same problem.

Comment: There was no additional follow up on this matter. Things changed and it was not important  anymore, for me at least. Thanks everyone for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find some information on EMC's PowerLink site (http://powerlink.emc.com).

There's not much to the application.  You feed files into at and index them. It stores the indexed data in a database which it then queries to find the actual file location and name which it then displays.